# How can I compile & run helloworld.m file on linux

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to iphone development. Iphone development under linux is available through toolchain. I have installed toolchain2 in linux and created a file name "helloworld.m".

The code in file is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
        printf("Bismillah");
        return;
}
```

I tried to compile it using following command which creates a "helloworld.o" file.

```
root@mzeeshan-desktop:/usr/toolchain2# /usr/toolchain2/pre/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-g++ -c helloworld.m
```

after above command i tried to create executeable through the command given below which cerates helloworld executeable

```
/usr/toolchain2/pre/bin/arm-apple-darwin9-g++ helloworld.o -o helloworld
```

Now its time to run this executeable using the command `./helloworld` which says that 
"bash: ./helloworld: cannot execute binary file".

I dont know what to do can anyone help me how can i execute this program?

Also, am i in the right way to develop iphone app?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.10 with toolchain2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot run an executable built for iOS/ARM on Linux/x86[-64]. You need to upload the executable to an iOS platform (iPhone, iPod Touch, AppleTV 2G) to run it.

---

BTW, you need to [pseudo-sign](http://www.saurik.com/id/8) the binary file when you upload it to the iPhone

```
ldid -S helloworld
```

Comment: I dont have iphone. I am trying the above commands in linux terminal

Comment: @Zeeshan: Um what? You can't directly run the iOS executable in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is possible to write and run Objective-C programs on Linux, you'll need the Cocoa-Touch frameworks and the iOS SDK, which you cannot get on a Linux machine. So it isn't going to help you to write iPhone apps.

Comment: I looked into toolchain2 and it looks like you can develop for iPhone on Linux. I can't think of a more horrible way to work on iPhone apps, though.

Comment: It says 'some' apps. Not the best way to learn how to program iOS apps though, you'll spend more time than you ought to working around the toolchain.